# Java Finalize Method similar in python

Tags: python

I want to determine how can we determine if an object goes out of scope and perform some operations when object goes out of scope

In java we have a finalize method which is called by JVM when an object has no more references.

I am very new to the python world and want to determine if there is any similar way like Java Finalize where we can perform some operations before and object is destroyed or there are no more references to the object

Answer (score 4):

What you want is called a `destructor` of an object. Python has that concept using - `__del__` method of the class.

Example -

```
class FooType:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        print self.id, 'born'

    def __del__(self):
        print self.id, 'died'
```

The `__del__` method would be called when the object is about to be destroyed.

Now if you define the above class inside a python file , lets call it `test.py` , and add the following lines below it and run the python code, you will get the following result -

```
f1 = FooType(1)
f2 = FooType(2)

python test.py

1 born
2 born
1 died
2 died
```

Please note, the `__del__` destructor may not be called in all circumstances , and it would be more advised to use `contexts` for handling cleanup , etc.

Though a better way to handling cleanup , etc is through `contexts` , using the `with` statement . An example of `with` statement -

```
with open('file','r') as f:
    <some statements operating on f>
```

Once the `with` block ends, the interpreter calls the `__exit__` function of the variable - called `context manager` - which would be responsible for cleanup. (In above example , the `context manager` is `f` )

You can use [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) to create custom context managers.

Comment: It's important to note that `__del__` might not be called in some circumstances, such as when the interpreter is shutting down, so take care that what you want it to do is not absolutely essential. For example: closing a file, fine (since it'll be closed anyway when the process exits); deleting a temp file, might leave some temp files depending on when you clean up, if at all.

Comment: @AnandSKumar
I understood the __del__ part .So is the _del_ same as the Finalize method in java ,as I am from java background and this is my requirement and my java understanding with this is
Requirement :When I have no more reference to an object say authentication,then i call the logout method
Java solution:
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
     try {
         logout();        // call logout 
     } finally {
         super.finalize();
     }
 } 

So in python would it be like this 
def __del__(self):
  logout()

Comment: Yes, `__del__` is similar , they both have the same issues as well, and it is bad to depend on them for any kind of cleanups